# Control how queries are being created by datanucleus

Tags: java, mysql, jdo, datanucleus

Currently I am using datanucleus 4.0.2 for a project.
In some tables I have up to a million rows, which is usually not a problem for the db to handle.

However when datanucleus fetches all dependent elements it will generate a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    'my.com.CHILD_TABLE' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,
    `CHILD_TABLE`.`ID` # And alot of more fields
FROM
    `CHILD_TABLE` 
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT DISTINCT
            'my.com.MIDDLE_TABLE' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,
                `MIDDLE_TABLE`.`ID`
        FROM
            `MIDDLE_TABLE` 
               INNER JOIN
            `FIRST_TABLE` ON `MIDDLE_TABLE`.`MIDDLE_PARENT_ID_OID` = `FIRST_TABLE`.`ID`
        WHERE
            `FIRST_TABLE`.`TABLE_OWNER_ID_OID` = 5057520
                AND `CHILD_TABLE`.`PARENT_ID_OID` = `MIDDLE_TABLE`.`ID`)
```

For some reason mysql needs to scan all 1 million rows in child table for this. (This might be a query execution planner bug)

Converting it to this form

```
SELECT 
    'my.com.CHILD_TABLE' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,
    `CHILD_TABLE`.`ID`
FROM
    `CHILD_TABLE` 
INNER JOIN `MIDDLE_TABLE` 
    ON `CHILD_TABLE`.`PARENT_ID_OID` = `MIDDLE_TABLE`.`ID`
               INNER JOIN
            `FIRST_TABLE` ON `MIDDLE_TABLE`.`MIDDLE_PARENT_ID_OID` = `FIRST_TABLE`.`ID`
        WHERE
            `FIRST_TABLE`.`TABLE_OWNER_ID_OID` = 5057520
```

give magical results which only needs to scan 9 rows or similar.

Is it possible to control how datanucleus generates these queries?

Ps. I found a related post explaining the problmes with mysql when doing exists http://solutionfactor.net/blog/2011/11/06/mysql-inner-join-vs-exists-may-yield-better-performance/

**Updated the question with some code**
Here is how the entity relationships are set up:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
class ChildTable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    MiddleTable middleTable;
    // More fields
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
class MiddleTable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    ParentTable parentTable;
    @Persistent(mappedBy="middleTable", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    private Set<ChildTable> children;

}
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
class ParentTable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;

    MasterTable masterTable;
    @Persistent(mappedBy="parentTable")
    private Set<MiddleTable> children;
 }

// Master table code is left out for brewety, same set up

Query query = pm.newQuery(MiddleTable.class);
Collection<MiddleTable> entitySet;

try {
    query.setFilter("parentTable.masterTable == :masterTable");
    entitySet = (Collection<MiddleTable>) query.execute(masterTable);

}
finally {
    query.closeAll();
}
```

Basically what happens here is when executing the query datanucleus will also execute two native queries. 
The first one works well. It looks like the first raw query I posted except for the EXISTS stuff.

The second one is launched because children is in the default fetch group. This is what I want to reduce the number of queries. All children will be accessed later on.

Comment: it maybe is possible?, but you'd have to explain the class(es) and what operation you perform that results in that SQL in the first place

Comment: @NeilStockton updated the question with the entity classes. What do you have in mind?

Comment: and the log says? about why the second query is invoked? I know you can turn OFF "bulk fetch" of secondary fields via a query extension (in the documentation), but no idea if you can request inner join ... assuming this is the bulk fetch query you're referring to. Best way is look in their code as the start point

Comment: Well I gave up on this method. I think the core problem lies in mysql, it should not be slow for these particular queries. I ended up using custom result classes and two separate jdo queries (one for the middle class and one for the child class). Then I set up the relationship manually.